# Why document is not found in MongoDB, but read retry helps?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, database-migration, database-replication, sharding

Sometimes we observe the next case:

- We insert a document to MongoDB with write concern `w: 1` via `mongos` router that writes to `primary` replica of shard A.
- We read this document from MongoDB with default `local` read concern via `mongos` router that should read from `primary` replica of shard A.
- This `findOne` returns `null` as if the document is not found.
- (Actually it is Python driver `pymongo - find_one()` and it returns `None`).
- We sleep 0.1 seconds and retry the read.
- On step 2-5 the document is finally read successfully.

We found:

- Such cases are observed more often when a lot of documents are inserted to this collection quickly.
- We suspected such inserts lead to chunking and migration of chunk from shard A to shard B.
- While a document is migrating, could it be unavailable for reads for a short time?
- But there is only one insert to only one shard in `db.oplog.rs`, no `fromMigrate` flags.

Why does it happen? How to deal with it correctly?

These false-positive "not found"-s may lead to faulty atomic-find-or-create via `$setOnInsert`?

Comment: Some having the same issue [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongorepository-save-issue/12124/4) but no solution has been suggested at the time of writting this comment !